# Retrieve source code from PyBuilder/.pyb

Tags: python, decompiling, pybuilder

Is it possible to retrieve the source code from a PyBuilder/.pyb file, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Pybuilder and builder.py file are the project build management tool, they do not obtain any code.
See more details about pybuilder [here](http://pybuilder.github.io)